# Сравнить массивы

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть задача сравнить два массива, то есть первых два символа каждого элемента, если совпадают добавляем в новый массив один элемент первого массива, сравнивать элементы нужно первый с первым второй со вторым и тд.
Есть небольшие наработки но они не работают:

```
var arrayOfCorrectAns = new Array();
var arrayOfCorrectTwoSim = new Array();
var compareMas = Array();

var arrayOfEmpty = [2104, 3506, 3606, 3114, 2501, 2907];
var sourceObject = [2104, 3306, 2207 3114, 2402, 2708];


if ((sourceObject.length == 6) && (arrayOfEmpty.length == 6)) {

    for (var i = 0; i < sourceObject.length; ++i) {
        arrayOfCorrectTwoSim.push(sourceObject[i].toString().slice(0, -2));
    }
    console.log(arrayOfCorrectTwoSim);
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfEmpty.length; ++j) {
        arrayOfCorrectAns.push(arrayOfEmpty[j].toString().slice(0, -2));
    }

    for (var b = 0; b < arrayOfCorrectAns.length; ++b) {
        for (var k = 0; k < arrayOfCorrectTwoSim.length; ++k) {
            if (arrayOfCorrectAns[b] == arrayOfCorrectTwoSim[k]) //сравниваем элементы
            compareMas.push(arrayOfCorrectAns[k]); // добавляем если совпали в результирующий массив
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Укажите как именно не работают.

Comment: Выводит пустой массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш скрипт какой-то глючный насквозь.

```js
(function(){
  var first  = [1122, 6587, 'IMissYou', 6548]; // Первый массив на проверку
  var second = [5422, 6534, 'IDoNotMissYou', 6548]; // Второй массив на проверку
  var result = []; // Результат

  first.forEach(function(e, i){ // e - элемент, i - номер ключа
    var tmp; // Кое-кто докопался до области видимости, пришлось добавить объявление, вы рады? Сарказм
    if(tmp = second[i]) // Если во втором массиве есть элемент с таком же месте
      if(e.toString().substring(0, 2) == tmp.toString().substring(0, 2)) // Если первые два символа элементов равны
        result.push(e); // Кидаем в результат элемент первого массива. ВНИМАНИЕ: третий и далее символы могут отличаться!
  });

  console.info(result); // [6587, 6548] - первый элемент хоть и равен второму по первым двум символам, но разнится с ним по дальнейшим числам
})();
```

Comment: А как можно  сохранить только элемент первого массива first ? Я там в вопросе немного не уточнил.

Comment: @DimSamoylenko, Там из `first` и сохраняется. В строке `result.push(e);`. В `e` - элемент `first`, в `tmp` - элемент `second`.

Comment: Одним циклом было бы лучше. И кто объявлять переменные будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Хм, там только один цикл - `first.forEach`.
Какие переменные? Там только `tmp` возможно где-то используется. Но из названия видно что оно временная. Да и это пример.

Comment: Цикл - это цикл, а `first.forEach` - это вызов функции. Переменные - `tmp` не объявлена.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Чувак, чего ты докапываешься? Код выполняет работу, возложенную на него? Выполняет. Большего и не требуется.
`forEach` - это перебирающая конструкция, которая в любом случае использует цикл - там, внутри своей реализации.
А про `tmp` я ответил.